# Practical limit of variadic template

Tags: c++, templates, variadic

The C++ standard says that I can use "any" number of arguments in a variadic template. These are usually used by recursively using a fixed finite number of the arguments in the template, then calling the template again without those first few arguments (example copied from [here](https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2014/variadic-templates-in-c/)):

```
template<typename T>
T adder(T v) {
  return v;
}

template<typename T, typename... Args>
T adder(T first, Args... args) {
  return first + adder(args...);
}
```

I'm thinking about using this in a project, and I am wondering about the practical limits. Will I make my compiler cry if I use 100 arguments? 1000? 1 million? Just thinking about the mangled names for a function instantiation gives me a headache. I'm also imagining 1000 different instantiations if I start with 1000 arguments.

I'm contemplating using something like this to make a header-only library that the compiler will inline and optimize for me, so while the compiler will know at compile-time how many template arguments there will be, I won't know at library-design time. In context, it very well might make sense for there to be dozens or hundreds of template arguments.

Comment: To way to know without trying it. And I'd use fold expressions instead of recursion when possible.

Comment: The language standard has some recommended minimums (typically 1024 for template related things). However, each compiler vendor is free to decide what their limits are (which can be less than the recommended minimum). You'll need to consult the documentation for your particular compiler.

Comment: I wrote my own array / vector like type which had a variadic template constructor. For usual cases like 10 parameters it worked just fine.
But with a quicksort-test of just 10.000 elements I couldn't compile it any more and the compile time was very much increasing.
As a workaround I introduced a constructor for large argument lists similar to the std::vector one. It uses std::initializer_list. Surprisingly the produced assembly was very reasonable - not bad.
As far as I know clang has a template recursion limit of 1024.

Comment: You might be better off using `std::accumulate` or `std::reduce`. They will handle a large number of input values well.

Comment: Honestly, if a function has 10 arguments, it is already too much so who care about the actual limit?